# Objective-C Separate Class for Delegates

Tags: ios, delegates

i have separate class **"CoordinationController.h"** it contains some protocols

Example:

```
@protocol CoordinationControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)startScrollingUpToXPosition:(NSInteger)xPosition scrollingUpToYPosition:(NSInteger)yPosition;

@end
```

but i didn't implemented any **"CoordinationController.m"** file. but this protocol implemented in all the viewController class except my "ControllerManager.m" class.

and i have one "ControllerManager.h" class. here i have list of controller object in NSArray.

ControllerManager.h

```
@interface THSControllerManager : NSObject

{

    NSArray *_controllers;
} 

@end

ControllerManager.m

@interface ControllerManager ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *controllers;

@end

@implementation ControllerManager

@synthesize controller = _controllers;


- (id)init

{

    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
         self.controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];
    }

}

@end
```

now i have to invoke the the protocol to all the implemented controller. how can i achieve.

Either i have to create object of my `CoordinationController` class in `ControllerManager` class or any other way is there kindly suggest me. and there is any other way to achieve the same functionality kindly comment it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `CoordinationController` to instantiate. You just have a file with some protocol(s) in it. Your best option is probably just to use the protocol to define the methods that the compiler should check are implemented. When you create / set `viewController1` and `viewController2` they should specify the protocol as being implemented. When you come to use the instances you should use `respondsToSelector:` to check that the required method is actually available.

You could also / instead use `conformsToProtocol:` but if you're going to make a check it might as well be for the actual method, not the protocol itself.

Comment: wain, i implemented protocol in all the controller class. i done another way also i created on class in method in "CoordinationController" class. and i called from "ControllerManager" with "viewController" Object as parameter to invoke protocol. there is any other way to do that same thing.

Comment: I don't really understand your comment. Can you show the code (in your question) where you define these things and how you want to call the method?

Comment: wain, i created separate class file "CoordinatorController.h", there that protocol is written. and i have another class file "ControllerManager.h and .m" its contain list of "viewController" object is NSArray. all the "viewController" implemented that protocol. now my question is, i want to call that protocol method from "ControllerManager" using that "viewController" objects. which way i can achieve this. 1. i need to create any class method in "CoordinatorController" and call that method in "ControllerManager" to invoke protocol through passing "viewController" object.

Comment: You don't need to create anything. Just call the method. You can add some protection with `respondsToSelector:`.

Comment: Thank you, i got the solution with ur ans.